# TreeShaking vs. Deep Imports

Tags: javascript

imagine the following two ways of importing an interface.

```js
import { AnyInterface } from '@eng/lib/interfaces/AnyInterface';
import { AnyInterface } from '@eng/lib';
```

Is there any difference in bundle size considering those two ways of importing? The second way references the whole library, but webpack actually should be so clever to handle removing not used classes etc. via treeshaking and not import all of them in each component, right?

I'd expect the bundle size to be equal sized.

Comment: "Is there any difference in bundle size considering those two ways of importing?" — This strikes me as something that would take you less time to test than it took to write this question.

Comment: This depends on how each individual library is written. The library creator is mostly repsonsible for writing code in a way that webpack can understand how to "tree shake".